# Slicing dataframe index with date in yyyymm in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a df:

```
          ABC   XYZ
192607   1.00    2.00 
192701   3.46    6.93 
192803   6.44    12.89
```

How do I slice the data for particular years, say 1927 and 1928.I'm trying the below code:

```
df['1927':]
```

But it doesn't work? How do I do this by **NOT** converting the index in yyyy-mm-dd format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Options for an index of an **integer** dtype:

```
In [18]: df.loc[(df.index//100).isin([1927,1928])]
Out[18]:
         ABC    XYZ
192701  3.46   6.93
192803  6.44  12.89

In [27]: df.loc[192701:192812]
Out[27]:
         ABC    XYZ
192701  3.46   6.93
192803  6.44  12.89

In [29]: df.query("192701 <= index <= 192812")
Out[29]:
         ABC    XYZ
192701  3.46   6.93
192803  6.44  12.89
```

Options for an index of a **string** dtype:

```
In [21]: df.loc['1927' : '1929']
Out[21]:
         ABC    XYZ
192701  3.46   6.93
192803  6.44  12.89

In [23]: df.loc[df.index.str[:4].isin(['1927','1928'])]
Out[23]:
         ABC    XYZ
192701  3.46   6.93
192803  6.44  12.89

In [24]: df.loc[df.index.str.match('192[78]\d{2}')]
Out[24]:
         ABC    XYZ
192701  3.46   6.93
192803  6.44  12.89

In [31]: df.query("'192701' <= index <= '192812'")
Out[31]:
         ABC    XYZ
192701  3.46   6.93
192803  6.44  12.89
```